# mysql join query where multiple rows have same key value

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table, in a third party database, that has two tables like these:

```
HISTORY
========
ID | ORDERED
1    PEAS
1    CARROTS
1    SPINACH
2    CARROTS
3    PEAS
3    CARROTS

PEOPLE
=====
ID | NAME
1    Jamal
2    Sharon
3    Mark
```

I am trying to create a MYSQL query that will return all the PEOPLE who ORDERED both PEAS and CARROTS. The results would be:

Jamal, Mark

When I try this with the OR operator, I get all three people:

```
SELECT a.ID from people a 
INNER JOIN history b on a.ID=b.ID 
WHERE b.ordered='PEAS' OR b.ordered='CARROTS'
```

When I try this with the AND operator, I get no people.

```
SELECT a.ID from people a 
INNER JOIN history b on a.ID=b.ID 
WHERE b.ordered='PEAS' AND b.ordered='CARROTS'
```

How can I write a query to get the names of the people who ordered peas and carrots given the table structure I have to work with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JOIN twice, once for each condition:

```
SELECT a.ID
FROM people a 
JOIN history b on a.ID=b.ID AND b.ordered='PEAS'
JOIN history c on a.ID=c.ID AND c.ordered='CARROTS'
```

If `history` can contain duplicates, or to be defensive, add `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID
FROM ...
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. There may be other ways to accomplish this, but I am marking this as the correct answer. I also appreciate that, for someone at my level, it made me aware that sequential joins can be used. Thanks again!

Comment: @Chester cool. FYI this is also the best performing way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

Select all people from `people` and for each of them the `history` details, but only the people who ordered `PEAS or CARROTS`:

When you say "***all***" people, then you always begin your sql with the `people` table. When you say "***who have***", then you add the `LEFT JOIN`, e.g to the `LEFT` table (`people`) you `JOIN` the wanted details from the right table (`history`). And when you say "***but just the ones having the following details***", then you apply a filter, e.g. you use `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT 
    peo.ID, -- OPTIONAL
    peo.NAME,
    his.ID, -- OPTIONAL
    his.ORDERED
FROM people AS peo
LEFT JOIN history AS his ON his.ID = peo.ID
WHERE 
    his.ORDERED = "PEAS" OR
    his.ORDERED = "CARROTS"
;
```

Note: "--" means *commentar*.

### EDIT 1:

Important, a principle which you always should apply: Rename the `history.ID` column to `history.PEOPLE_ID` and add a new column `history.ID` as `PRIMARY KEY` column, in order to uniquely identify each `history`record.

```
HISTORY
-------
ID   PEOPLE_ID   ORDERED
1    1           PEAS
2    1           CARROTS
3    1           SPINACH
4    2           CARROTS
5    3           PEAS
6    3           CARROTS
```

`PEOPLE` table remains the same.

### EDIT 2:

NO no, it should be an `AND` in the `WHERE` clause. My fault. I corrected it.

### EDIT 3:

NO no, it should be an `OR` in the `WHERE` clause. My fault. I corrected it. AGAIN :-)))

Comment: Thank you. The AND yields zero results. It seems as if this looks for a matching ID in the History table, then looks in that row for peas AND carrots.

Thanks for the advice on best practices, there is a unique key in the history table, I just simplified it for the question.

Comment: @Chester You're welcome! Now, try without the `WHERE` clause first and tell me if you're receiving something.

Comment: Yes, it should be `OR`! My mistake. I already corrected from OR to AND :-) Use `OR`, please.

Comment: Hi, yes I got results without a where clause. Using the OR operator, I get the person who only ordered carrots.

Comment: That's strange. Because i run it now with my query from my answer and works perfect: all records except the "spinach" one are displayed.

Comment: Yes, but it is is not the desired result. The results should NOT include the person who only ordered carrots. The results should only include IDs 1 and 3 — those who ordered BOTH peas and carrots. 

Bohemian's answer correctly accomplishes this and his additional recommendation to use DISTINCT further refines the results to make them even more useful.